# Partition pandas dataframe into equal parts based on common ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

#### Given an id in a pandas dataframe, how can I create a new column that has an additional id that maxes out at a count of 5 for each ID. almost like "batches" of rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1],
                    [2, 1],
                    [3, 1],
                    [4, 1],
                    [5, 1],
                    [6, 1],
                    [7, 1],
                    [8, 2],
                    [9, 2],
                    [10, 3],
                    [11, 3],
                   [12, 3],
                   [13, 4],
                   [14, 5],
                   [15, 5],
                   [16, 5],
                   [17, 5],
                   [18, 5],
                   [19, 5],
                   [20, 5]])
df.columns = ['ln_num', 'id']
print(df)
#expected output
expected = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1],
                    [2, 1, 1],
                    [3, 1, 1],
                    [4, 1, 1],
                    [5, 1, 1],
                    [6, 1, 2],
                    [7, 1, 2],
                    [8, 2, 3],
                    [9, 2, 3],
                    [10, 3, 4],
                    [11, 3, 4],
                   [12, 1, 2],
                   [13, 1, 2],
                   [14, 1, 2],
                   [15, 1, 5],
                   [16, 4, 6],
                   [17, 4, 6],
                   [18, 4, 6],
                   [19, 3, 4],
                   [20, 3, 4]])
expected.columns = ['ln_num', 'id', 'grp_id']
print(expected)
```

so for example if I have 11 rows with ID=1 I need 3 different unique Id's for these subset of alerts. 1. lines 1-5, 2. lines 6-10 3. line 11

The closest I've gotten so far is using a groupby with +1 offset that gives me a new grp_id for each id, but doesn't limit this to 5.

```
df = df.groupby('id').ngroup() + 1
```

```
I've also tried by head() and nlargest() but these don't sort ALL lines into batches, only the first or top 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by getting all the points where you know the transition will happen:

```
df[1].diff() \     # Show where column 1 differs from the previous row
     .astype(bool) # Make it a boolean (true/false)
```

We can use this selection on the index of the dataframe to get the indices of rows that change:

```
df.index[df[1].diff().astype(bool)]
```

This gives output: `Int64Index([0, 7, 9, 12, 13], dtype='int64')` and we can check that rows 0, 7, 9, 12, and 13 are where column 1 changes.

Next, we need to break down any segments that are longer than 5 rows into smaller batches. We'll iterate though each pair of steps and use the `range` function to batch them:

```
all_steps = []  # Start with an empty list of steps
for i, step in enumerate(steps[:-1]):
    all_steps += list(range(step, steps[i+1], 5))  # Add each step, but also any needed 5-steps
```

Last, we can use `all_steps` to assign values to the dataframe by index:

```
df['group'] = 0
for i, step in enumerate(all_steps[:-1]):
    df.loc[step:all_steps[i+1], 'group'] = i
```

Putting it all together, we also need to use `len(df)` a few times, so that the `range` function knows how long the interval is on the last group.

```
steps = df.index[df[1].diff().astype(bool)].tolist() + [len(df)]  # range needs to know how long the last interval is
all_steps = []
for i, step in enumerate(steps[:-1]):
    all_steps += list(range(step, steps[i+1], 5))
all_steps += [len(df)]  # needed for indexing
df['group'] = 0
for i, step in enumerate(all_steps[:-1]):
    df.loc[step:all_steps[i+1], 'group'] = i
```

Our final output:

```
    0   1   group
0   1   1   0
1   2   1   0
2   3   1   0
3   4   1   0
4   5   1   0
5   6   1   1
6   7   1   1
7   8   2   2
8   9   2   2
9   10  3   3
10  11  3   3
11  12  3   3
12  13  4   4
13  14  5   5
14  15  5   5
15  16  5   5
16  17  5   5
17  18  5   5
18  19  5   6
19  20  5   6
```

If you want the groups to start at 1, use the `start=1` keyword in the `enumerate` function.